# unit test for function that read parquets and return pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unit-testing, pyarrow

I have a simple python function that reads parquet in given directory and return a dataframe:

```
import pyarrow as pq
import pandas as pd

def read_data(data_dir):
   df = pq.to_pandas(data_dir)
   df = df[['userID', 'itemID', 'action']] 
   return df
```

it reads all parquet files in given data directory, and pick only 3 of columns from dataframe then return it.

Can someone provide me guidance for unit test? Maybe I'm overthinking, but I feel like pyarrow and pandas is complicating my process - should I mock parquet files?

Answer (score 0):

You can just write some tables to a tmpdir and read them back in your unitest

With pytest you can do:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

def read_data(data_dir):
   df = pq.read_table(data_dir, columns=['userID', 'itemID', 'action'])
   return df.to_pandas()


def test_read_data(tmpdir):
    pq.write_table(
        pa.table({
            'userID': [1,2,3], 'itemID': [4,5,6], 'action': ['a', 'b','c']
        }),
        tmpdir / "file.parquet",
    )
    df = read_data(str(tmpdir))
    assert isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame)
```